# Make Cron expression - Weekly(Monday only)

Tags: c#, cron, cron-task, cronexpression

I need to make a cron expression which need to be fire;

1. Monday Only (Every Monday only)
2. Hourly Start from 10:30 am
3. Need to fire until 20:30pm

I need to start 10:30 am and need to finish on 20:30 pm (Monday only)

How Can I make that Cron expression?

Comment: I don't think cron expressions support finishing time

Answer (score 0):

This should do it: `30 10-20 * * 1`

From left to right, this will fire your job every 30 minutes, for hours 10 through 20, any month, any day of the month, on each Monday.

Table lifted from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

```
# * * * * *  command to execute
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
 # │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
 # │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 # │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 # └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

Comment: that site appears to use something called `Quartz Scheduler` which is not the default implementation of cron. is that what you're using? Try [this](http://www.cronchecker.net/check?utf8=%E2%9C%93&statement=30+10-20+*+*+1+something.sh&button=)